# How to simplify a specific formula?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Example sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E38dkv6gBnKM0s16t0WT1TzNNDvpTeAvbxColQq0wck/edit?usp=sharing).

Basically, I want to find out how many days have had their values entered, then average the totals across the number of days. If a day's value hasn't been entered it will be blank, but the value can be 0.

What I've been using is this:

```
=IF(isnumber(G2), sum(A12:G12)/7,  
if(isnumber(F2), sum(A12:F12)/6,  
if(isnumber(E2), sum(A12:E12)/5,  
if(isnumber(D2), sum(A12:D12)/4,  
if(isnumber(C2), sum(A12:C12)/3,  
if(isnumber(B2), sum(A12:B12)/2,  
A12))))))
```

Which seems like a cumbersome way to do it, plus the number of days tracked will be variable in the near future. I know I could replace it with `IFS()` and `isblank()`, but is there a more scalable option that doesn't require so much manual entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("A12:"&ADDRESS(12, COUNTA(A2:2), 4)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: That did it! I have another similar sheet that has analytic data in the cells to the right of the entry fields. Is there any issue using this?

    =AVERAGE(INDIRECT("A13:"&ADDRESS(13, COUNTA(A2:2)-1, 4)))

Specifically, COUNTA(A2:2)-1 to prevent that field from being counted towards the average.

Comment: @Nick yeah, that's it if you wanna exclude H column: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCgeA.png